# Structure in a Blazor App and why can't I have one?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor, blazor-server-side

So, I've created a bog-standard Blazor Server App using `dotnet new blazorserver`. Opened the solution in VS and run it.

Fine.

If I add a new folder, say `Components` and add a new Razor Component in that folder - `Component1.razor` - then in my `index.razor` page I add a using statement to point at my `Components` folder and the mark up to include the component itself and run the app, the index page shows, but there is no sign of my component. Further looking at the source of the rendered HTML, I see an empty element `<component1></component1>`

If I move my new component to the `Pages` folder and rerun the app, the component renders properly.

If I create a sub-folder under `Pages` and move my component to there and rerun the app, the component fails to render.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I expecting too much? **Should** I be able to have a structure that means I don't have to have every single component in a single folder?

Comment: i'm not sure if i confuse this with React, but probably component names have to start with an uppercase letter like `<Component1/>` otherwise they might be misinterpreted as html tags and render as `<component1></component1>`

Comment: Visual Studio should have given you plenty of alarm signals...  But it does run the app, as per the previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you missing the point of `_Imports.razor`. You can put your pages anywhere they will be found by the `@page ""` attribute. If you want your components to be available either put a reference to their folder via the `_Imports.razor` or use the `@namespace` attribute/directive to override the namespace from folder its is in to another that is being imported. There is nothing special happening here. The template puts a using statement in for the "Shared" folder. This is why `App.razor` in the root folder has access to them.

Example `_Imports.razor` (From a project with name/default namespace of `PolymorphicApi)`

```
...
@using PolymorphicApi
@using PolymorphicApi.Shared
```

If you do not want to use `_Imports.razor`, you may not want to make all your components available. You can use `@namespace` in the component. This is the same as overriding the default namespace in a `.cs` file.

Example :

```
@namespace PolymorphicApi
```

A component using this statement could be in any subfolder and will be available as the root namespace is already imported.

As a side note: `_Imports.razor` can be thought of as a chunk of razor statements that will be imported into all razor components in that folder down. You do not have to use it just for namespaces. For example you can use an @inject statement. I do this to have Localization in every component by default.

Comment: Does adding injects to _imports affect the lifetime of the injection?